# Difference between at and to

Tags: grammar

Which sentence is correct?

*Please confirm that you want this sms to be sent **to** 10 clients?*

or

*Please confirm that you want this sms to be sent **at** 10 clients?*

Comment: What would be your own guess?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you send sth *to* an address and you send sth *to* a group of people/clients. 
You can also send sth *to* somebody *at* an address.

I'd use the other one to send sth *at* a point of time.

To sum up:
"Confirm that you want this sms to be sent **to** 10 clients?"
But: "Confirm that you want this sms to be sent **at** 10 pm?"

Answer (score 1):

Clients are persons. The preposition "to" is used for showing who receives something. We usually use "at" for a place. Sometimes "to" is also used for a location or place. Pease send it at/to my address.

So the first sentence with the use of "to" is grammatically correct.

Answer (score -1):

This is a confusing distinction.  When going to or sending something toward a destination, we typically use "to," but when arriving or leaving something at a location we use "at."

We are going to the park
We are meeting at the park.
Please take this envelope to my office.
Please leave this envelope at my office.